# How do I use extends for interface using typescript?

Tags: typescript

Below is my origin code

```
interface customerInfo {
    Success: boolean;
    Code: string;
    Message: string;
    Result: {
        name: string
        tel: number
    }
}

interface accountInfo {
    Success: boolean;
    Code: string;
    Message: string;
    Result: {
        xxx: number
        vvv: string
    }
}
```

How can I use extends for this code?

```
interface outer {
    Success: boolean;
    Code: string;
    Message: string;
    Result: Object;
}

interface customerInfo extends outer.Result {
        name: string
        tel: number
}

interface accountInfo extends outer.Result {
        xxx: number
        vvv: string
}
```

Is code above correct?
The content of interface customerInfo and accountInfo is under result Object.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You could make `outer` generic and the type parameter will be the result type:

```
interface outer<T> {
    Success: boolean;
    Code: string;
    Message: string;
    Result: T;
}

interface customerInfo extends outer<{
    name: string
    tel: number
}> {
    //Other members 
}

interface accountInfo extends outer<{
    xxx: number
    vvv: string
}>{
    //Other members 
}
```

In the above type the type parameter is an inline interface declaration, but if you want to reuse it, it might be best to use a named interface. Ex:

```
interface customerInfoResult {
    name: string
    tel: number
}
interface customerInfo extends outer<customerInfoResult> {
    //Other members 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest thing is just to extend `outer` with the new `Result` type:

```
interface customerInfo extends outer {
  Result: {
        name: string
        tel: number
      }
}
```

That will complain if you try to assign a different object to `Result` in a `customerInfo`.

But, really do you want to do this? Do all of your responses have `Code`, `Message` and `Result` whether they succeed or fail?

Much simpler to define `customerInfo` and `accountInfo` up top and then include them inside the `outer` interface which itself is modified to discriminate between success and failure cases:

```
interface customerInfo {
    name: string
    tel: number
}

interface outerSuccess {
    Success: true;
    Result: customerInfo | accountInfo;
}
interface outerFail {
    Success: false;
    Code: string;
    Message: string;
}
type outer = outerSuccess | outerFail;
```

Now when you use it:

```
if (response.Success) { ... can access Result here ... }
else { ... can access Code and Message here ... }
```

P.S. `tel: number`? Should probably be a string as well.